# Controlling website (html/javascript) through Python (jQuery/Ajax) without browser

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, web

I am trying to write a small Python-script that opens/loads content from a website (no-browser) and changes values on the website. The website was obviously written for graphical user input through a webrowser, however I now need to change those values automatically and can no change those settings manually.

Below you can find snippet examples for the corresponding HTML and javascript code that changes the values of the homepage. I extracted this code through the "code inspector" and don't have access to those.

The website is running locally in my network through http:\*.*.*.*:8080 where *.*.*.* is my IP and 8080 is the port (both fixed).

I assume that the following line is essential, however I'm unclear how to reproduce that with Python:

```
 $.ajax(root+'/settings/' + control + '?set='+val).fail(display_error('cannot_set', control));
```

I was looking into several Python packages such as flask, http, request, however I haven't found a good answer how my problem can be solved.

In the end, I'd like to have a Python method with a simple argument call close to this:

```
def change_crop_x(val):
   # Here needs to be the python code I'm unsure of
   return True # True if value was succesfully changed
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Best,
Florian

```
<div class="form-group" id="crop_host">
  <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Crop</label>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <label class="col-xs-2 nopadding" for="range_crop_x">X:</label> <input class="col-xs-10" id="range_crop_x" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <label class="col-xs-2 nopadding" for="range_crop_y">Y:</label> <input class="col-xs-10" id="range_crop_y" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example of content to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly9JM.png)

```
  var crops = ["crop_x", "crop_y"]
  var crop_holders = []
  for (i in crops) {
    var control = crops[i]
    crop_holders.push({
      val: get_val('#range_'+control),
      id: -9999,
      upd: function(val) {},
      cmd: function(control){ return function(val) {
        if (val == 0) {
          val = 1;
        }
        $.ajax(root+'/settings/' + control + '?set='+val).fail(display_error('cannot_set', control));
      }} (control)
    })
  }
```

```
if (config.curvals.crop_x != undefined) {
      $('#range_crop_x')
        .val(config.curvals.crop_x)
        .change(scheduleUpdateW(crop_holders[0]));
      $('#range_crop_y')
        .val(config.curvals.crop_y)
        .change(scheduleUpdateW(crop_holders[1]));
    } else {
      $('#crop_host').hide()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the elements you provided, I guess the values you are trying to change are from the application IP Webcam.

When you modify the value of CROP X by moving the slider, the following HTTP request is sent to the server: GET http://[YOUR_IP_ADDRESS]:8080/settings/crop_x?set=[VALUE] where the [VALUE] is an integer between 0 and 100 and refers to the position on the slider.

I am not very familiar with python but, as far as I know, to achieve the same effect with it, you can use the library named "requests" (among others) and the code should look like this (don't forget to replace [YOUR_IP_ADDRESS] with your own IP address):

```
import requests

def change_crop_x(val):
    URL = "http://[YOUR_IP_ADDRESS]:8080/settings/crop_x"
    PARAMS = {'set':val}
    RESPONSE = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
    if RESPONSE.status_code == 200:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The same can be done for CROP Y.

For the zoom slider, the corresponding request is GET http://[YOUR_IP_ADDRESS]:8080/ptz?zoom=[VALUE], with [VALUE] being an integer between 0 and 100.

```
def change_zoom(val):
    URL = "http://[YOUR_IP_ADDRESS]:8080/ptz"
    PARAMS = {'zoom':val}
    RESPONSE = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
    if RESPONSE.status_code == 200:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```